# Specific file extension moving error

Tags: python

I've written a small script with the purpose of searching the entire C:\ of any specific file extension and copying it to a folder of your choosing:

```
import os
import shutil


def move_all_ext(extension, source_root, dest_dir):
    # Recursively walk source_root
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(source_root):
        # Loop through the files in current dirpath
        for filename in filenames:
            # Check file extension
            if os.path.splitext(filename)[-1] == extension:
                print("copying file: %s" % filename)
                # Move file
                shutil.copy(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), os.path.join(dest_dir, filename))



print('Welcome to the file find/copy module\n')
print('You will be asked to enter a directory name and the file type that you want to copy\n')
# Prompt new folder name
print('Enter new directory name:')
newDir = input()
print('Enter the file extension (.pdf, .txt, etc..)')
fileExt = input()

# File directory path
os.makedirs(os.path.join('C:\\Users\\Nick\\Documents\\', newDir))

# Move all specific files from C:\ to C:\Users\Nick\Documents\
move_all_ext('.' + fileExt, "C:\\", os.path.join('C:\\Users\\Nick\\Documents\\', newDir))
```

While running the script i have a few errors that i don't fully understand:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\Nick\Documents\programming\Python\ext_copy_dest.py", line
36, in <module>
     move_all_ext('.' + fileExt, "C:\\", os.path.join('C:\\Users\\Nick\\Documents\\', newDir))   File
 "C:\Users\Nick\Documents\programming\Python\ext_copy_dest.py", line
 20, in move_all_ext
     shutil.copy(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), os.path.join(dest_dir, filename))   File
 "C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\shutil.py",
 line 235, in copy
     copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)   File "C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\shutil.py",
 line 115, in copyfile
     with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Nick\\Documents\\PDF\\README.txt'
```

I'm assuming its a problem with a symlink, is there a way to write an IF statement to ignore any 'Permission denied' issues?

Comment: Use `try-except PermissionError` instead of an if-statement.

Comment: I feel silly for not figuring that out, thank you it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evert pointed out a try-except was the best option to get around the exceptions:

```
    if os.path.splitext(filename)[-1] == extension:
        try:
            print("copying file: %s" % filename)
            # Move file
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), os.path.join(dest_dir, filename))
        except PermissionError:
            print('Could not copy file: %s' % filename)
        except shutil.SameFileError:
            print('Could not copy duplicate file: %s' % filename)
```